# How do I get nmap to list all devices connected to my ATT wifi?

Tags: wifi, ping, nmap

Using Ubuntu, I attempted to list all devices connected to my wifi with

```
$ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.83/24     
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-19 10:35 CDT
Nmap scan report for amazon-6f0692a99.attlocal.net (192.168.1.66)
Host is up (0.069s latency).
MAC Address: 4C:17:44:23:23:B0 (Amazon Technologies)
Nmap scan report for 09AA01AC44161BRB.attlocal.net (192.168.1.99)
Host is up (0.31s latency).
MAC Address: 18:B4:30:87:D6:4E (Nest Labs)
Nmap scan report for dsldevice.attlocal.net (192.168.1.254)
Host is up (0.0031s latency).
MAC Address: 08:9B:B9:39:41:F2 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for w-main-System-Product-Name.attlocal.net (192.168.1.83)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 23.16 seconds
```

Per the output above, there appears to be 5 devices with internal IP addresses currently connected.  However, the browser-based GUI for the router correctly shows 8 additional devices connected that do not appear on the nmap output such as

[image]

Pinging 192.168.1.83 produced no results either even though there is definitely an active device connected with that IP.

Why is there a difference between nmap's output and the browser view of the router as well as pinging it?

Answer (score 0):

- Not every host will reply to a ping, so using nmap or another tool does not provide any guarantee that your sweep will yield complete results
- for practical purposes, that means that when running a ping scan with nmap or another tool, some machines are stealth and not reported
- even running a port scan against those machines may yield no result if they have no open port that can be probed by nmap
- the conclusion is that you have to keep in mind the limitations of software tools, and that you may not see the whole picture
- As you correctly assumed, the best is to look directly in the web interface of your router
- but some of the hosts may be connected to an **ethernet** port and not wifi, thus they are not wifi clients but they are still connected to the same router through a different connection. And they may be DHCP clients too, or have a static IP address.
- it's even possible that the ethernet ports on your wifi router use another range than 192.168.1.0/24...
- The MAC address that begins with 80C5F2 is a device whose maker is AzureWave Technology Inc. if it helps
- a tool like [Airodump-ng](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng) would be more appropriate for your purpose: scanning the airwaves and listing the devices connected to your access point